# smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host) > (mail.host)?

Tags: python, smtp

I have a scanning script that currently works by connecting to an SMTP server, printing the results and moving to the next server in the list. This is the first connect code:

```
def sendchk(listindex, host, user, password):   # seperated function for checking
try:
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host)
    smtp.login(user, password)
    code = smtp.ehlo()[0]
```

After the fail "except":

```
smtp.quit()
except(socket.gaierror, socket.error, socket.herror, smtplib.SMTPException), msg:
    print "[-] Login Failed:", host, user, password
    pass
```

I'm trying to get it to repeat the same code with the same host, adding a subdomain. "mail." I thought this would work:

```
smtp.quit()
except(socket.gaierror, socket.error, socket.herror, smtplib.SMTPException), msg:
    print "[-] Login Failed:", host, user, password
    sub1 = 'mail.'
    host2 = '{0}@{1}'.format(sub1, host)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host2)
```

But it jams, saying there's an issue in server list.
What would be the better way to inject the prefix to the host here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having tested it: if *sub1* is "mail." and *host* is "myhost.com" then `'{0}@{1}'.format(sub1, host)` will result in *mail.@myhost.com*. Is that really your subdomain name? I suppose it should be *mail.myhost.com*. If so then drop the "@" in your formatting string.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the @ was literal. I thought it connected the strings. Thanks, that worked.